# I need help solving this javascript challenge

Tags: javascript

In this challenge i have to Use arrow function syntax to compute the square of only the positive integers (decimal numbers are not integers) in the array realNumberArray and store the new array in the variable squared Integers .
https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/write-higher-order-arrow-functions

my code so far.

```
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];    
const squareList = (arr) => {    
  "use strict";    
  realNumberArray.filter((arr) => arr !== null && parseInt())    
  const squaredIntegers = arr;   
  return squaredIntegers;    
};    

const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);    
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Comment: and what do you think `parseInt()` does? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: filter returns a new array, you do nothing with it....

Answer (score 3):

You could take three steps:

- Filter intger only numbers with `Number.isInteger`.
- Filter only positive values.
- Map squared values.

```js
const isPositive = v => v > 0;

const squareList = (arr) => {    
  "use strict";    
  return realNumberArray
      .filter(Number.isInteger)
      .filter(isPositive)
      .map(v => v * v);
};    

const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];    
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);    
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `parseInt()` does not check if a number is an integer; it converts a string to an integer when applicable.

To check if a number is an integer, you can use `Number.isInteger()`.

In the below snippet, we are filtering out non-integers and negative values, and then computing the squares of all the remaining elements using `map()` with an arrow function.

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];    
const squareList = (arr) => {    
  "use strict";
  //removing decimals from the passed array
  arr = arr.filter((elem) => Number.isInteger(elem) && elem >= 0); 
  //computing the squares
  var squaredIntegers = arr.map((elem) => elem * elem);
  return squaredIntegers;    
};    

const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);    
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6,  -9.8,  3.14,   42, 6, 8.34,  -2];    

const squareList = (arr) => {
      "use strict";
      const squaredIntegers = arr.filter( (num) => num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0 ).map( (num) => Math.pow(num, 2) );
      return squaredIntegers;
    };

// test your code
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers)
```